# пришлось / мне нужно было

Tags: грамматика

I've always used `мне нужно было` to mean `I had to` / `it was necessary to` but today I came across `мне пришлось` which seems to mean the same thing. I can't find it in a dictionary but it looks like a past tense form. Google translates it as `I had`, but is it a common expression?

Comment: In my experience, Google Translate sucks. You should try http://context.reverso.net/перевод - you can enter words or phrases and get really good examples of usage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Мне пришлось* means exactly the same as 'I had to', that is, you did something because of the circumstances, you had no other way out but to do that, like in

> Я не успел на автобус, поэтому мне пришлось идти пешком.

It means "I was late for my bus, that's why I had to walk on foot."

On the other hand, *мне нужно было* means only 'it was necessary to', but not 'I had to', *мне нужно было* implies the existence of an alternative, like in

> Врачи говорили, что мне нужно было побольше ходить пешком, но я всё равно ездил на машине.

It means "The doctors said it was necessary for me to walk on foot more, but I still drove my car."

*Пришлось* is the past tense, singular, neuter gender form of the perfective aspect verb *прийтись*, here it is in a dictionary, the meaning we are talking about is #3: [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/прийтись](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C).

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks. Is пришлось ever used in the present/perfect tense?

Comment: @Echilon - Yes, the present tense is _мне приходится_ 'I have to', the future tense is _мне прийдётся_ 'I'll have to'. And I edited my answer a bit adding more info.

Comment: @Echilon - Hmmm, it seems like now the tendency is to write _мне прийдётся_ as _мне придётся_, without the _й_, but the variant with _й_ is definitely acceptable, [have a look](https://www.google.com.ua/search?tbm=bks&hl=uk&q=%22%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%22).

Comment: Nowadays "прийдётся" is uncommon and is considered wrong by many people, even if it is formally acceptable. At school we were taught that "прийду" is a mistake, but I don't remember about "прийдётся".

Answer (score 5):

You could translate `мне пришлось` as "I was forced to...". In other words, it is not simply "I had to", but with added implication that I didn't want to do this, but there was no other choice, as Yellow Sky pointed out.

> "Ну дела, - подумал Лось, -
>
> Не хотелось.
>
> А пришлось".
>
> ```
>    -Рената Муха
> ```

On the other hand, `мне нужно было` would be better translated as "I needed to...", as opposed to `я должен был`, which is a better equivalent of "I had to".